# QT Installer: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, compilation, qt-installer

I'm trying to set up the QT Installer following their manual (Im in Ubuntu):

https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html

I just compiled it with qmake and make commands and apparently without problems. The binaries were generated and none error message. But when I try to run any of the binaries files, I get this message:

"error while loading shared libraries: libinstaller.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I can see that libinstaller.so.1 is at the QT Installer lib folder. but I don't know how to link it.

$ls lib/

lib7z.a          **libinstaller.so.1**    libinstaller.so.1.0.0
libinstaller.so  libinstaller.so.1.0